# Discrepancy in Cosmos DB storage space metrics and document sizes

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

While investigating the balance of denormalization for our data, I am struggling with comparisons due to a discrepancy between the consumed storage as reported by the Portal metrics and raw measurements of the data performed through Data Explorer.  The details of my process:

- Created a new container with exclusionary indexing to lessen the impact of indexes on space consumption.
- Inserted 15,754 documents, each one 381 bytes in size.
- Confirmed the size of a few individual items via Data Explorer's "Query Stats".  Additionally, I ran a query to SUM the document sizes, which produced the expected value of 6,002,274 bytes.
- On the "Overview" tab of the portal's "Metrics" section, the container is reported with a "Data Size" of 15.24 MB and an "Index Size" of 861.18 kB.

This pattern holds when I add or remove documents:  the reported storage space remains more than twice the expected amount.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Am I comparing apples and oranges?

Comment: Hi, Jay. I wanted to see if you have an answer for this. If not, I can assist you if you are still seeking an answer. Regards, Mike

Comment: I ran a slew of test scenarios through, and basically found that there is at least a 600 byte overhead per document, even with an exclusionary indexing policy and using the "id" field as the partition key.  It gives me something to work on planning-wise, but I would love to understand more about what is happening behind the scenes, just to ensure that I am not doing something wrong on my side.

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT I have the same problem: 4 million rather small documents that take up 1.8 GB as text file on local disk, but 4.8 GB according to Cosmos DB metrics, so there is a difference of 3 GB. The automatically inserted meta properties like "_ts" account for about 1.2 GB, but 1.8 GB are unaccounted for. Can you assist?

Comment: I am no longer with Microsoft. I hope you are able to or have found a resolution for this. Again, apologize for the delay in responding with an update.

Comment: I am seeing this same behavior.